# Beautiful Soup to search spans based on regex

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a horrid html page that I need to parse.

I'm looking to capture the H2 title - I've managed this.  I also need to search for Stock and Stock On Order.   These last two fields are held in SPANS.  I can't use class : info alone as there many other fields with this class that I need to disregard.  I think the only way to do this is by searching the spans with regex.

Here's some sample HTML - note I've removed lots of HTML that I'm not interested in indicated by ...

```
..
..
<div class="innerListing">       
..
..    
    <div class="title">
            <a id="btl00_ContentPlaceHolder105" href="http://****"><h2 id="btl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_advertTitleWrapper" title="TitleText">
               TitleText</h2></a>
            <p class="sku">
            </p>
        </div>
...
        <div class="layout">

            <span id="btl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_ProductTypeLabel" class="label">Product Type:</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_ProductType" class="info">3 seat sofa</span>
          ...
            <span id="btl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_StockLabel" class="label">Stock:</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_Stock" class="info">5</span>
          ...
          <span id="btl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_StockOnOrderLabel" class="label">On Order:</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ctrl_SearchResultsWrapper_ctl05_Stockonorder" class="info">1</span>
         </div>
```

Here's my code so far.  It works but as mentioned above I'm getting too much data i.e. all classes='info'.   I only need Stock & SockOnOrder

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

#For Title
for header in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'innerListing'}):
    title = header.find("h2")
    print (title.text.strip())

#For Spans
for layout in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'layout'}):
    for info in layout.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'info'}):
        print (info.text.strip())
```

Whats the best way of searching with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, do you only want all the `span`s that have `Stock` in the `id` attribute?

If so, you could change your second `for` loop and ignore the ones not related to Stock/StockonOrder:

```
#For Spans
for layout in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'layout'}):
    for info in layout.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'info', "id":True}):
        if "Stock" in info["id"]:
            print (info.text.strip())
```

Note: You would need to add an extra attribute in your `find_all` call (`"id":True`) to avoid any KeyErrors. This is just in case there are some span tags that don't have any IDs - so that we may filter them out.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm getting an error : KeyError:'id'

Comment: @Leehbi Have you tried my code since I edited it? I added a little bit in the `attrs=` of the second `find_all`

Comment: oh yes - sorted.